# Error Object reference not set when using UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I had this error " **Object reference not set** .... " , I had checked my
code and I got that the error in **UpdatePanel** , when i removed it the
code worked well but I must use it to prevent all page reload .

```
<div>
   <fieldset style="width: 498px; text-align: right; padding: 5px; direction: rtl;">
       <legend>what do y think ? </legend>
       <div class="add-post">
           <textarea class="textarea" cols="3" rows="3" runat="server" id="txpost"></textarea>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVAddPost" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"
               ControlToValidate="txpost" ValidationGroup="AddUserPost">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </div>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPAddUserPost" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <div class="add-post-control">
                   <div class="post">
                       <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" ID="btAddPost" OnClick="btAddPost_Click" ValidationGroup="AddUserPost" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                       <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                           <span>
                               <img src="res/images/img.png" width="38" height="27" /></span>
                           <input type="file" runat="server" class="upload" id="FUFile" />
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btAddPost" EventName="Click" />
           </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </fieldset>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.textarea').focus(function () {
           $(this).animate({
               height: "80px"
           }, 500);
           $('.add-post-control').fadeIn(200);
       });
   </script>
</div>
```

Method:

```
protected void btAddPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AddpostfromFront();
}
private void AddpostfromFront()
{
    if (FUFile.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
        FUFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
        ftier.Addpostfromfront(LoggedUserID, "4", txpost.Value, tempVar, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: can we see the codebehind?

Comment: @SonerGönül the error here  if (FUFile.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)

Comment: that is C# code and I don't see any here.

Comment: Are you sure there is anything in `FUFile.PostedFile`?  Have you debugged and looked at your objects?  My guess is that instance is null.  Checking `ContentLength` on a null object would throw this error.

Comment: you probably have the code in the wrong order, if you showed up the code behind that is causing the issues we could help you.

Comment: you aren't showing us everything.  where does `FUFile.PostedFile` come from? in the code that you gave us, it doesn't exist, you just call it out of nowhere.  trace back the `FUFile.PostedFile` as far as you can go, if it isn't given any data up to the point of the error, that is the problem

Comment: @Malachi this is the fileupload <input type="file" runat="server" class="upload" id="FUFile" />

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do instead of check the length of the file is to use a method that is built into `PostedFile` to check if there is a file to begin with.

if you look on the [Microsoft page for `PostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  your code would look more like this

```
Private void AddpostfromFront()  //I don't like your naming on this, should be AddPostFromFront
{
    if (FUFile.HasFile)
    {
        string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
        FUFile.SaveAs(tempVar);
    }
}
```

to use these methods you may have to use the ASP control instead of the HTML tag,  `<asp:FileUpload></asp:FileUpload>` you will have to adjust the attributes to fit your situation and naming scheme.  This would replace your HTML tag  `<input type="file" runat="server" class="upload" id="FUFile" />`

I think that you are meshing two processes into one and getting confused as to what your code should be doing.

---

no clue what `ftier` is and why it has the same method name with the same bad naming scheme, or what it is doing with that information.

---

you should do this in 3 steps

1. upload the file
2. save the file
3. if you need to display the file then do so with the file that is saved, not the file that is being uploaded.

Comment: it return NULL , I think the problem with UpdatePanel

Comment: `FUFile.HasFile` returned Null?  it should return either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Should be able to use code on MSDN for file uploader:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile(v=vs.110).aspx . Note they use an `asp:FileUpload` control, not the client-side `input type=file` control you are using, though, which might not have the `HasFile` property, and would explain why it's null.

Comment: @vapcguy, that is a good point! I hadn't thought about that at the time of posting.  thank you